# C#: Disappearing arrow after OnRenderSplitButtonBackground override

Tags: c#, background, toolstrip, toolstripbutton

I was trying to change the background of a `ToolStripSplitButton` using an override, but by doing that the arrow on the dropdown disappears when hovering on the button.

Code:

```
protected override void OnRenderSplitButtonBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Item.Selected)
    {
        base.OnRenderSplitButtonBackground(e);
    }
    else
    {
        Rectangle button = new Rectangle(0, 0, e.Item.Size.Width - 12, e.Item.Size.Height - 1);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, button);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Olive, button);

        Rectangle dropdown = new Rectangle(e.ToolStrip.Items[0].Size.Width - 1, 0, e.Item.Size.Width - 32, e.Item.Size.Height - 1);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, dropdown);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Olive, dropdown);
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: ToolStripSplitButton]

I know that `OnRenderArrow` exists, and I also tried to override that, but it looks like it's "overwritten" by the `dropdown` Rectangle in `OnRenderSplitButtonBackground`.

How should I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast the base class that the `e.Item` property returns (the ToolStripItem) to the [ToolStripSplitButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripsplitbutton?view=net-5.0) class, you will get all the relevant properties to draw the different parts of the split button.

Bounds properties such as, [ButtonBounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripsplitbutton.buttonbounds?view=net-5.0),  [DropDownButtonBounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripsplitbutton.dropdownbuttonbounds?view=net-5.0), [SplitterBounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripsplitbutton.splitterbounds?view=net-5.0). State properties; [ButtonPressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripsplitbutton.buttonpressed?view=net-5.0), [ButtonSelected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripsplitbutton.buttonselected?view=net-5.0), [DropDownButtonPressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripsplitbutton.dropdownbuttonpressed?view=net-5.0), ...etc.

As for the arrow part. You need to invoke the `OnRenderArrow` method.

**Example**

```cs
protected override void OnRenderSplitButtonBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Item.Selected || e.Item.Pressed)
        base.OnRenderSplitButtonBackground(e);
    else
    {
        var sb = e.Item as ToolStripSplitButton;
        var button = sb.ButtonBounds;
        var dropdown = sb.DropDownButtonBounds;

        button.Width--;
        button.Height--;
        dropdown.Width--;
        dropdown.Height--;

        var br = sb.ButtonPressed ? Brushes.Gainsboro : Brushes.White;

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, button);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Olive, button);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, dropdown);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Olive, dropdown);

        OnRenderArrow(new ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs(
            e.Graphics, e.Item, sb.DropDownButtonBounds, e.Item.ForeColor,
            ArrowDirection.Down));
    }
}
```

[image: SOQ65328100]

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked like a charm!